# How do we add a data-testid to an error field of a textField component

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library

I tried this

```
<TextInputField value={emailValue} error={emailError} errorProps={{ 'data-testid': 'emailError' }} helperText={emailError && 'Enter email address in format: yourname@example.com'} type='email' length={100} onChangeAction={setEmail} label='Email' />
```

But this does not set a data-testId on the error field.

Answer (score 2):

I had to put `FormHelperTextProps={{ 'data-testid': 'emailError' }}` and not errorProps